# Where does Chrome save its bookmarks on Windows?

Tags: windows-7, windows, google-chrome, bookmarks

I'm trying to recover a Windows system from backups and can't seem to find where Chrome saves its bookmarks.

Does anybody know where Chrome saves its bookmarks on Windows?

Answer (score 76):

`%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default`

Go to that folder and you can see a file with a name "Bookmarks".

Comment: Note: The AppData folder is hidden by default. Either just type the name in the addressbar or set the explorer to show hidden folders.

Comment: You don't need to change visibility of hidden files & folders to access AppData, open Run dialog using `Win+R` and enter `%AppData%` and go to the location, it will open `Roaming` directory by default, now press `Alt+Up Arrow` to go to its parent folder, and there you have the folders `Local`,`LocalLow` and `Roaming`, now can navigate to the Chrome's directory.

Comment: %APPDATA% actually throm me to the followinf location: C:\Users\{User Account}\AppData\Roaming

Comment: You can't seem to import this file (with no extension) via Chrome GUI so you need to close Chrome, copy it to same location & then re-open https://superuser.com/a/838663/160219

Answer (score 10):

On my PC (Windows Vista) i can find the bookmarks file (and also cache/history/etc.) in this location:

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default
```

Comment: note that in Chrome's newer version instead of the Default folder there will be a "Profile 1" folder.

Comment: What do you call "the bookmark file". Is it the .bak file?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the built-in Bookmark Manager by typing

> chrome://bookmarks/

in Chrome's address bar.

The bookmarks are stored in the "bookmarks" and the "Bookmarks.bak" files which are located in these locations:

In **Windows XP** and older versions:

%USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default

or

C:\Documents and Settings\username\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default

In **Windows Vista** and newer versions:

%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default

or

C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default

You can open these files with notepad and see their content.

Please note that in Chrome's newer versions instead of the "Default" folder there will be a "**Profile 1**" folder.

Comment: The bookmarks.bak file is not always the same version that the one you have on your computer, it depends when it did the backup, sometimes there's a big difference between this file and the actual state of your bookmarks collection.