# Google Chrome. The date of add web-page to favorites

Tags: google-chrome

I would like to find out the date of adding concrete web-page to favorites in Google Chrome. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the information provided here: [Where does Chrome save its bookmarks on Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/376366/where-does-chrome-save-its-bookmarks-on-windows) then when you click with right mouse button on afile and choose properties, you might be able to see when the date was on which the file/bookmark was created.

Though it depends on what operating system you are using. Just to be sure Google the following: "where does Chrome store bookmarks"