# Import Chrome bookmarks from previous installation

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks, import

My Windows got corrupted and I had to reinstall. I had not synchronised Google Chrome, so I cannot get my previous bookmarks.

I have the previous bookmark file (which is in JSON format, not HTML) but cannot import it to my new Chrome installation. I have tried copying the bookmark file of previous installation and overwriting the new one, but even after that only newly bookmarked items are shown.

My question is as follows: can I import a JSON bookmarks file into Google Chrome?

Answer (score 9):

Following procedure works:

1. Turn off synchronization (Chrome menu > Signed in as  > Disconnect your Google Account (do not forget to keep Chrome data saved on the computer)
2. Close Chrome
3. Replace Bookmark file in Chrome's User_Data folder with your own version
4. Open Chrome
5. Export your bookmarks as HTML (Chrome menu > Bookmarks > Bookmarks manager > Organize > Export bookmarks)

You end up with your Bookmark file converted to HTML. Then you can turn on synchronization (Chrome menu > Sign in to Chrome) and import your bookmarks from HTML file.

If you do not need to merge your old bookmarks with current bookmarks synchronized in your Google account, it is perfectly sufficient to do steps 1. to 4. and then just sign in to Chrome.

Comment: From user [Alexey F Shevelyov](http://superuser.com/users/461172/alexey-f-shevelyov): Please kill all the chrome processes in order for the JohnyCash answer to work. If you don't - it just would not work. Chrome has background processes running even though the browser is closed - so go to you task manager or CMDs and kill all the processes first then do how Johny Cash said.

Comment: I had to also turn off the bookmarks bar, turn off "allow stuff to continue to run in background after Chrome is closed" and set the default page to *not* be the "new-tab" page because that showed the bookmarks bar for me.  Then your instructions worked.  Not sure which of those made the difference for me.

Comment: For those like me who were having trouble finding the "Export bookmarks" option. From within the bookmark manager, click the 3 dots on the right: https://i.imgur.com/4vAj128.png (Chrome Version 113.0.5672.126)

Comment: This is also possible without disabling sync, without closing Chrome, and without replacing the user data folder. I had a bug/virus that was related to my user data folder, so overwriting the entire folder wasn't safe. Instead, I created a new temporary Chrome profile. I then used this answer's general principal, but I only overwrote the "Bookmarks" file from backup. FYI, on Macs, Chrome creates a folder for each profile in `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/`. My new one was "Profile 2" so I replaced the "Bookmarks" file there. - I'm out of space here. Ask for more info if needed.

Answer (score 7):

I was unable to make Chrome and Firefox restore my bookmarks from the `Bookmarks` or `Bookmarks.bak` json files.
But I found this really helpful online tool to convert those json files to an HTML file that you can then just import via the top-right corner in the `chrome://bookmarks/ screen`:

https://rongjiecomputer.github.io/chrome/bookmark-recovery/#windows

Comment: like a charm... thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's too late for answer but maybe it's help someone who has same problem

Instead of copying `bookmarks` file to `Default` folder copy it to `ChromeDefaultData` too.

Both folders are located here

`C:\Users\<Your Name>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data`

Remember first close all of your chrome tabs!

Answer (score 0):

Is the JSON Bookmark backup file from Firefox or earlier versions of Chrome?

Firefox has the ability to Backup/Restore Bookmarks in JSON format, I am not sure about Chrome as I don's use it much.

If it is a Firefox file or if Chrome's JSON files are compatible with Firefox's JSON restore (which I am not sure), you can install Firefox temporarily to import JSON, and then export it back to HTML format.

Much easier would be to find, if there is already a Chrome extension that can achieve this (which I'm sure will already be available).

Comment: This is not also working after importing a popup appears asking whether to proceed with it and i clicked okay but nothing happened

Answer (score 0):

It seems like Chrome* stores a folder on `C:\Users\<user_name>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\` for each *Person* logged (which you can see on *Menu > Settings > People*). So there might be a folder called:

`C:\Users\<user_name>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Profile 1\`

**Try copying your *Backup* file into that folder** (after closing Chrome, as [mahdi azarm](https://superuser.com/users/661285/mahdi-azarm) pointed out). That worked for me, but it might depend on which Chrome version you're using.

---

* At least the version I'm using, which is 56.0.2924.87. If someone knows which versions have this functionality, please feel free to edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

chrome can only import bookmarks in html format
to convert the `Bookmarks` file (in json format) to html, we can use
https://rongjiecomputer.github.io/chrome/bookmark-recovery/

the imported bookmarks will appear at `Bookmarks Bar / Imported`

relevant code

```js
function Bookmark(raw) {
    this.tree = JSON.parse(raw);
    this.html = '';
    this.count = 0;
    this.first = true;
}
function chromeTime2TimeT(time) {
    return Math.floor((time - 11644473600000000) / 1000000);
}
Bookmark.prototype.walk = function(node) {
    if (node.type === 'folder') {
        this.html += '<DT><H3 ADD_DATE="' + chromeTime2TimeT(node.date_added) + '" LAST_MODIFIED="' + chromeTime2TimeT(node.date_modified) + '"';
        if (this.first) {
            this.html += ' PERSONAL_TOOLBAR_FOLDER="true"';
            this.first = false;
        }
        this.html += '>' + node.name + '</H3>\n';
        this.html += '<DL><p>\n'
        node.children.forEach(this.walk.bind(this));
        this.html += '</DL><p>\n';
    } else { // node.type == 'url'
        this.html += '<DT><A HREF="' + node.url + '" ADD_DATE="' + chromeTime2TimeT(node.date_added) + '">' + node.name + '</A>\n';
        this.count++;
    }
}
Bookmark.prototype.parse = function() {
    this.html = '<!DOCTYPE NETSCAPE-Bookmark-file-1><META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8"><TITLE>Bookmarks</TITLE><H1>Bookmarks</H1>\n';
    this.html += '<DL><p>\n';
    var roots = this.tree.roots;
    this.walk(roots.bookmark_bar);
    if (roots.other.children.length > 0)
        this.walk(roots.other);
    if (roots.synced.children.length > 0)
        this.walk(roots.synced);
    this.html += '<style>dt, dl { padding-left: 12px; }</style>\n';
}
```

```js
            var bookmark = new Bookmark(reader.result);
            bookmark.parse();
```

for firefox, there is a similar tool at
https://www.jeffersonscher.com/ffu/bookbackreader.html

Answer (score 0):

This worked on MAC:

1. Exit Chrome completely. Kill any running Chrome process from the terminal.
2. From terminal, go to `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome`
3. Find the folder under which Bookmarks files are present. For example:

```
~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome $ find . -name Bookmarks -print 
./default/Bookmarks
./Profile 3/Bookmarks
./Profile 2/Bookmarks
./Guest Profile/Bookmarks
```

4. Find out the correct bookmark file you're looking for, and copy it to the default folder:

```
cp "Profile 2/Bookmarks" default/
```

5. Restart Chrome.