# Where does Chrome save its bookmarks on Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-8, google-chrome, bookmarks

I have two laptops and a desktop. When I travel I take, of course, one of the laptops. The thing is, I have some good bookmarks in all three of my computers, but they are all different. I would like to "dump" all my bookmarks in one folder [like windows Explorer] and reselect them there. Here it comes the question:
Where does Chrome save its bookmarks on Windows 8.1?
Thanks
Dan

Comment: This question has already been asked here: http://superuser.com/questions/376366/where-does-chrome-save-its-bookmarks-on-windows

The answer should be the same for Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

`C:\Users\USER_NAME\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default`

It will be in the form of a **File**. Open it with any browser or Notepad and you will see something like(for a bookmark for https://www.facebook.com/):

> {    "checksum": "edba30322dceb747d98c41a9d00c625c",
>
> "roots": {
>
> ```
>   "bookmark_bar": {
>
>      "children": [ {
>
>         "date_added": "13047878301592284",
>
>         "id": "5",
>
>         "name": "Facebook",
>
>         "type": "url",
>
>         "url": "https://www.facebook.com/"
>
>      }, {....*etc*.....
> ```

**HOWEVER:**

The easiest way to solve your situation wouldn't be to interfere with the bookmark file, but rather export the bookmarks from Chrome in **Bookmarks>Bookmarks Manager>Export**.

You will get a HTML file. Transfer it to your other computer, then **Import** the html file into Chrome bookmarks.

An **Imports** bookmark folder will be created (seen on the bookmark toolbar) and you can easily organise them in the **Bookmarks Manager**(or download the **SuperSorter** extension from the Chrome Store which also removes duplicates automatically).
By the way, by signing in in Chrome, you can easily sync all your bookmarks which solves all your problems.

Answer (score 0):

#### Where does Chrome save its bookmarks?

> Wondering where your Chrome bookmarks are stored? If you want to make
>   a copy of your bookmarks we recommend you export them as an HTML file
>   which can then easily be imported into other browsers. You can do this
>   by following these instructions:
>
> - Click the Chrome menu on the browser toolbar.
> - Select Bookmarks.
> - Select Bookmark manager.
> - Click the Organize menu in the manager.
> - Select Export bookmarks.
>
> Chrome will export the bookmarks as an HTML file
>
> Tip: You can use a simple text editor program to open this file
>
> However, if you're just wondering where they are on your Windows computer, they are located in
>
> ```
> ...\Chrome\User Data\Default\Bookmarks
> ```
>
> Full extensions might look like
>
> ```
> C:\Documents and Settings\<USER NAME>\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Bookmarks
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> C:\Users\{<USER NAME>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default
> ```

Source [Google Chrome Bookmarks Location](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/yWZeXbOmU80)